# How to post multiple div data to sql

Tags: php, html

So I Have The following code, I am trying to post the multiple data in the div (cart) to my sql database,how do I get the right code to post the following to my sql database?

If its not possible for multiple names on the match, how do i get it to insert multiple matches at once?

I am beginner level on php, please help, if you can draft for me even a different but relatable model

most of the answers i find online can only post  but this one is a cart so I only need the data from the div to be posted not edited

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Add Records in Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

        include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {       
            $match = $_POST['match'];
            $selection = $_POST['selection'];
            $odd = $_POST['odd'];
            $totalOdds = $_POST['totalOdds'];
            $stakeAmount = $_POST['stakeAmount'];
            $payout = $_POST['payout'];

            $insert = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO `receipts`(`Match`, `Selection`, `Odd`,  `Total Odds`,   `Stake Amount`, `Payout`) 
                                        VALUES ('$match','$selection','$odd','$totalOdds','$stakeAmount','$payout')");

            if(!$insert)
            {
                echo mysqli_error($db);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Records added successfully.";
            }
        }

        mysqli_close($db); // Close connection

    ?>
        <div class="cart">
            <div class="title">Bet Slip</div>
            <div id="box" class="boxlit" >
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="box" data-id="4" name="Match">Lanus - Godoy Cruz<div name="selection">Draw</div><div class="crtTotal" name="odd">3.05</div></div>
                    <div class="box" data-id="8" name="Match">Deportivo Pasto - Envigado<div name="selection">Away</div><div class="crtTotal" name="odd">4.70</div></div>
                    <div class="box" data-id="9" name="Match">Union Manabita - Emelec<div name="selection">Home</div><div class="crtTotal" name="odd">8.25</div></div>
                    <div class="box" data-id="12" name="Match">New Jersey Copa - FC Motown II<div name="selection">Home</div><div class="crtTotal" name="odd">3.35</div></div></div>
                    <br>
                    <div>Total Odds: <b id="ct1" name="totalOdds" >475.42</b></div><br>
                    <div>(N$)Stake: <input id="stake" type="number" name="stakeAmount" value="5"> NAD</div><br>
                    <div>Payout: N$ <b id="payout" name="payOut" >2377.10</b></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bet">
                </form>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is strange to “post the contents of a div”, that’s what form controls such as input do. Are you absolutely sure you need to do this? Is there something making this HTML that you can tap instead?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "hidden inputs" - form fields which are submitted back by the browser, but not visible to the user. (But remember the user *can* still edit them, because everything the browser does is under their control.)

Comment: @chrisHaas im not sure, can you please suggest for me a suitable approach to submit the data in the cart as given, where by the user's selection can go into my sql database

Comment: @IMSoP okay, how do I edit the inputs to my code so the y can submit the cart data?

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection because of the POST variables used directly in the SQL command - use a [Prepared Statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to help mitigate this threat!

Comment: How is the "cart" populated here initially? Where is the "cart" data stored ( session, cookie, localStorage, database etc )?